# Migrating from jboss 5 to 7

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I've been tasked with trying to migrate some existing apps from jboss5 to jboss7.

I don't know much about EJBs or Hibernate so this is an interesting challenge for me.

Currently this is where i'm stuck on:

```
...
14:42:12,727 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Authorization.ear"."AuthorizationClient-7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Authorization.ear"."AuthorizationClient-7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "AuthorizationClient-7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "Authorization.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:123) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011058: Failed to install component PermissionManager
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'org.calgb.authorization.client.permission.IPermissionCache' for binding org.calgb.authorization.client.permission.PermissionManager/permissionCache
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.processBindings(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:252)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.access$000(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor$1.handle(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:206)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deployComponent(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:202)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:95)
    ... 6 more
```

Any help is appreciated. Let me know what else you'd like me to post.

Comment: I don't know what that means and I haven't found anything related from googling

Comment: which part of it you don't understand?

Comment: The entire error. How to fix it.

Comment: The error is saying that your app cant find `IPermissionCache`. Was there some dependency jar that you may have forgotten to include or deploy before hand?

Comment: Nope. I'm looking at the IPermissionCache file in my Authorization project. It's definitely there.

Comment: That doesn't mean JBoss class loader is finding it. Your packaging of the app may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

check your application.xml + jboss-deployment-structure.xml if it points to required war/jar files